# PHP how to convert an image to Binary and use ones and noughts as variables in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, binary, converters

Hi I'd like to convert an image to binary ones and noughts and then use the ones and noughts as jquery variables so one `var 0 = $(#on).attr('checked', true) var 1 = $(#on).attr('checked', false)` so that I can make an image out of checked and un-checked checkboxes Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds bizarre. Maybe you could provide some more details on what you are doing and then we can advise on the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds pretty cool! I think you need the function imagecolorat ([link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)) to get the color value of each pixel, then create the checkboxes (after first deciding which colors you would consider 'one' and 'nought').

Good luck! And if you have more specific questions, don't hesitate to ask.

EDIT:

[Here](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?t=39594&) is an example of someone determining the average color from an image. It's not the same as what you're doing, but you should be able to use much of it.

EDIT 2:
[This](http://timbrockman.com/2009/06/ascii-quick-fun-with-php-gd-extensions/) ASCII art generator may just do almost exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Hi thanks for your tip. I was going to use bitmap i.e black and white, no grey so no problems deciding colours its either on or off no? My php knowledge is pretty limited any other tips would be appreciated

Comment: I included a link that I think does almost exactly what you are looking for. Just substitute his `nbsp;` for an empty checkbox and his `$` for a checked checkbox, and you're pretty much set.